# How do i Reset the headset icon in my phone Programmatically

Tags: android

I am using LG E410 running on android 4.1 and the phone has an headphone icon at the notification bar even if the headphone is not connected. This means for me to answer a call, i have to put loud speaker on.

Comment: Thats the problem of your phone,this has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not at all a question for this platform but try cleaning your headphone port on your phone. I've been through similar situation. It can be dust otherwise water. Try drying the phone with blow dryer :)